# "error": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: typescript, heroku, graphql, typegraphql

I ran into a problem after deploying my app to Heroku. The playground outputs an error.

> "error": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
> [image]

When run from the terminal with npm start, my queries and mutations are working. Here is a picture of the result:
[image]

But in the heroku app, I am getting the JSON syntax error. I am not parsing json anywhere, also I have not changed anything, both the git and the heroku repos are the same. Why I am getting an error on Heroku? How can I debug where the problem occurs?

Here is the serve.ts:

```
 dotenv.config();
    
    const graphqlPath = process.env.GRAPHQL_PATH || 4000;
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    const dbUrl: string = process.env.MONGODB_URL!;
    
    const auth = jwt({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
        credentialsRequired: false,
    })
    
    mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
        autoIndex: true,
    }).then(() => console.log("connected to mongo")).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    
    async function startApolloServer() {
        const schema = await getSchema();
        const app = express();
        const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
        app.use(
            cors({
                origin: '*'
            }),
            bodyParser.json(),
            auth
        );
    
        const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema,
            introspection: true,
            plugins: [
                ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
                ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
            ],
            context: ({ req }) => {
                const user = req.user;
                const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] as string || req.socket.remoteAddress;
                const context: Context = {
                    req,
                    user,
                    ip,
                }
                return context;
            },
        });
    
        await server.start();
        server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    
        await new Promise(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port }));
        console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}/${graphqlPath}`);
        return { server, app };
    }
    
    startApolloServer();
```

The response I got from the server is:
[image]

Comment: _"I am not parsing json anywhere"_ yes you are. `bodyParser.json()`

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot this one, but I have added it later and before that the program still was not working and giving the same error.

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine the cause but it's almost certainly the case that your server is returning some kind of response in a different format. For example perhaps an error like a 404 with no body

Comment: I am getting 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: There you go then